# My question is about Disconnects

Tags: equipment

Ok, I am an old dude with arthritic hands and would like to know just how hard is it normally to attach a disconnect to a post. I push as hard as I can but have to hit the top with a rubber hammer for it to finally connect.
Would this be over the top, or normal for someone with my problem hands.
I might advise that all the disconnects are brand new, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Is this about kegging?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like you're talking about corney keg ball locks. When used correctly they should attach with minimal effort. By lifting the lock ring and pressing on the nipple.

**I suspect you are connecting liquid fittings to gas nipples.**

Ball locks have two fittings gas and liquid. Gas are usually white or gray, liquid are usually black.

Gas (white or gray) fittings fit both liquid and gas nipples with ease.

**Liquid fittings (black) only fit liquid nipples. Though with force they will go on gas lines. They will be very difficult to attach and remove.**

If ball locks are still difficult to use, pin locks are easier when concisering the force needed.

*If talking about brew system lines like cam locks, tri-clamp are go on with much less effort though some dexterity is needed.*

Comment: Looks like you picked it in one, I diddn't know the post's were different.

Answer (score 0):

When my disconnects and kegs were new, they took a bit of force to couple.  Not enough that it warranted a hammer, but I had to lean into them.  A little bit of keg lube around the gasket on the posts let them slide on with ease.  Now that they're worn in a bit, even that isn't necessary.

Comment: Another very helpful suggestion, many thanks,I keep forgetting about using the lube.